# check if argparser already has arg defined

Tags: python, argparse

How can I detect if an argument already exists in an `ArgumentParser`? For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
import argparse
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument("--arg1")
if not has_arg(arg_parser, "--arg1"):
   arg_parser.add_argument("--arg1")
```

In this example it seems pointless, but I have a use case where `has_arg` would be useful. I have utility functions that take an `arg_parser` and add a bunch of arguments to it. These utility functions share some common arguments, and sometimes I need to call more than one of these functions, which would repeat a few arguments and would throw an exception. How can I handle this case? (I'm looking for something more principled than just a generic `try except`, ideally some function like `has_arg` as in my example)

Comment: `ArgumentParser` takes a `conflict_handler` parameter.  The default handler raises an error if there's a repeat in one of the flags.  An alternative handler attempts to resolve the issue - I believe by removing the earlier duplicate flag.  An argument may have multiple flags, e.g. '-f' and '--foo'.

Comment: The current 2 handlers are `argparse._ActionsContainer._handle_conflict_error` and `argparse._ActionsContainer._handle_conflict_resolve`.  They could customized.  I've explored some bugs related to the `resolve` handler, but haven't tried much further customization.

Comment: `list(parser._option_string_actions.keys())` is the list of currently defined flags.  So you could check your proposed flag, `'--arg1'` against that list.

Comment: `ArgumentParser` throws an exception if you try to add an argument it already has. It appears to me that `try/except` is the *exact right* method you should be using. I'm not sure why you think otherwise.